# Is it possible to put multiple conditions in a th:classappend attribute

Tags: thymeleaf

I've been racking my brains on this for a while and I'm pretty sure I'm getting the syntax wrong.

Basically I have a `<div>` and want it to have the `class="hidden"` unless two thymeleaf conditions are met.

- I want the class 'hidden' unless there's an error present on the input.

This works on it's own:
`th:classappend="${#fields.hasErrors('month') == false} ? 'hidden'`

- I want the class hidden unless the value of the input is not null.

This works on it's own:
`th:classappend="${applicationData.month == null} ? 'hidden'"`

Is there anyway to concat these two conditions into one th:classappend? I'm struggling with getting that working at the moment. Something like this doesn't seem to work for me

```
<div id="date-met" class="date-container" th:classappend="${#fields.hasErrors('month') == false} ? 'hidden' || ${applicationData.month == null} ? 'hidden'" >
  <input id="month" name="month" type="text" th:value="${applicationData.month}">
</div>
```

Thanks in advance and apologies if it's a stupid question!

Comment: Can you use `( condition_one || condition_two ) ? 'hidden'` - so `th:classappend="${ ( #fields.hasErrors('month') == false || applicationData.month == null ) ? 'hidden' }">`. The parentheses may not even be necessary - just for clarity.

Comment: You can probably simplify that further by using `not #fields.hasErrors('month')` - and knowing Thymeleaf there are various different approaches which could also work - e.g. two separate `<div>`s [using `th:if`](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf#conditional-evaluation) - or with Spring (if you are using Spring) even more options.

Comment: @andrewJames thanks for the reply, I think your first suggestion worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
( condition_one || condition_two ) ? 'hidden'
```

So in your case that would be:

```
th:classappend="${ ( #fields.hasErrors('month') == false || applicationData.month == null ) ? 'hidden' }">
```

The parentheses may not even be necessary - just added for clarity.